# Adding notification of USB (add/remove) in JNI (OSX) - Fails

Tags: macos, notifications, java-native-interface, usb

I used the following code:

[How to know when a HID USB/Bluetooth device is connected in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918429/how-to-know-when-a-hid-usb-bluetooth-device-is-connected-in-cocoa)

and added it to my jni library. Notification methods never gets called.

Then I tested the code in a small app (without in java / mostly C code). I works all good.

My guess is that Java is preventing the notification to take place.

Any ideas on what I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because no run loop is being run in the Java/JNI environment.

Take a look at how [javahidapi](http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/source/browse/jni-impl/HIDManager.cpp?r=0095c71ffa6b2f1faa53789c8c6ae5ae9c8458af) is implemented, specifically how it creates a separate thread to run `hid_runloop_thread()`, which then calls `CFRunLoopRunInMode()` until it returns a finished/cancelled status.

Note that run loops are thread-specific, so you need to do your `CFRunLoopAddSource ()` and `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification()` calls from the same thread before calling `CFRunLoopRunInMode()`.